# Unity3d c++ plugin

Tags: c#, plugins, header, unity-game-engine, .lib

I am currently working on a Unity3d 4.0 Pro project where i am trying to link the tngaming vest to unity. The only SDK ( http://tngames.com/pages/Developers ) i have available is a C++ .h and a .lib file. As far as i understand from the documentation ( http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/Plugins.html ), i should simply put the two tngaming.h and tngaming.lib into my assets folder and do the following code:

```
[DllImport("tngaming")]
private static extern int SetUpJacket();
```

And that would allow me to call the function `SetUpJacket()`. However i get the `DllNotFoundException: tngaming  error.`

Anyone who got some information doing something similar who can help out?

Comment: Is the `tngaming.dll` in your Unity project's `Assets/Plugins` folder? When you run the .exe, is the DLL in the same directory as the .exe?

Comment: As far as i know, there is no dll, just a .h and a .lib file. Secondly initially I'm just trying to get it to work and as such i am not exporting my unity to any exe file at this point. It is not working in the unity work window.

Comment: I'm not positive, but I think you _must_ use a compiled .dll.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair That's [correct](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html).  Also [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729562/how-to-compile-c-sharp-application-with-c-static-library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all for your assistance.. The actual goal was to find a way to change unmanaged c++ code (.h and .lib file) to a unmanaged .dll and then create a c# wrapper..

It took a lot of very obscure searching but i managed to find a page that did exactly what i needed in a guide form.

http://waterhobo.com/?p=28

At the bottom of the page, there is a link in the line "Here is the source code i made" for those who want to skip the programming parts and just use the TN Gaming Vest in C#.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html

> Once built, the bundle should be placed in the Assets->Plugins folder in the Unity project. Unity will then find it by name.

MacOS libraries are `.lib`, Windows libraries are `.dll`, and Linux libraries are `.so`. The other commenters are incorrect; plugins do not *have* to be in .dll format. I believe (not sure) that .dll's will work on Mac as well.